# How to edit only one single cell at first row and last column cell (Not all cells) in swing jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
table_taskAllocation.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                
                try {
                    int column=table_taskAllocation.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(arg0.getX());
                    
                    int row=arg0.getY()/table_taskAllocation.getRowHeight();
                table_taskAllocation.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    
                    serialNumber=(int) (table_taskAllocation.getModel().getValueAt(table_taskAllocation.getSelectedRow(),0));
    genStatus=allocatedTaskService.getStatus(serialNumber);
                        
                    String value = (String) table_taskAllocation.getModel().getValueAt(table_taskAllocation.getSelectedRow(), 7);
                    /* validations */
                    if(value.matches("Ready..")) {
                        btnPauseTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnEndTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnResumeTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnStartTask.setVisible(true);  
                    }
                    else if(value.matches("Started..")) {
                        btnResumeTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnStartTask.setVisible(false); 
                        btnPauseTask.setVisible(true);
                        btnEndTask.setVisible(true); 
                    }else if(value.matches("Resumed..")) {
                        btnResumeTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnStartTask.setVisible(false); 
                        btnPauseTask.setVisible(true);
                        btnEndTask.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else if(value.matches("Paused..")) {
                        btnStartTask.setVisible(false); 
                        btnPauseTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnEndTask.setVisible(false); 
                        btnResumeTask.setVisible(true); 
                    }else {
                        btnStartTask.setVisible(false); 
                        btnPauseTask.setVisible(false);
                        btnEndTask.setVisible(false); 
                        btnResumeTask.setVisible(false);
                    }

                    if(value.matches("Started..") || value.matches("Resumed..")) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IF");
                        textField = new JTextField();
                        DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(textField);
                        
                        TableColumn tableColumn = table_taskAllocation.getColumnModel().getColumn(7);
                        tableColumn.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
                        cellEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);
                    }else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, value);
                    }
            textField.getText());
                    
                        table_taskAllocation.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Enter");
                        table_taskAllocation.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                                    String value = (String) table_taskAllocation.getModel().getValueAt(table_taskAllocation.getSelectedRow(), 8);
                                    String replay = allocatedTaskService.insertRemark(serialNumber, value);
                                    if(value.trim().length() != 0) {
                                        ToastMessage message2 = new ToastMessage("Remarks "+replay);
                                        message2.display("P");
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("Key Pressed");
                                }
                            });
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.info("Doesn't selected any row!");
                }
                /* validations end*/
            }
        });
```

How to edit only one single cell at first row and last column cell
(Not all cells in the same column, only one cell) in swing jtable. I have to edit only one single cel at first row and 7th column cell in jtable.

I can created a text field in last column and top cell only. but I can edit all cell at the same column.
I want to edit/set text field in the top cell only, no need to edit at the bottom cells.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to edit only one single cel at first row and 7th column in jtable.

Override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the `JTable`.

Something like:

```
table = new JTable(...)
{
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        if (row == 0 && column == 6)
           return true;
        else 
           return false;
    }
};
```

> I can created a text field in last column and top cell only

You should NOT add a JTextField (or any component) to the table. You just add your String data and the appropriate editor will be used to edit the data.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Editors and Renderrs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for some basic information.